# Populating table rows from an observableArray using Jquery Templates

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using knockoutjs v1.2.0 and Jquery Templates. I would use data-bind: foreach etc but I found out it only appears from v2.0.0 of knockoutjs. So I'll have to go with jquery templates.

My aspx file has this code:

```
....
....
....
<tbody data-bind="template: {name: 'tasksTemplate', foreach: form.model.tasks}">                           
                            </tbody>                                
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script id="tasksTemplate" type="text/html">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="Selected" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: ${isSelected}" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id="CableCode" data-bind="options: CableCodes, value: ${CableCodeId}, optionsText: 'Code', optionsValue: 'Id'" style="width: 95%"></select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select style="width: 95%"></select>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="datePicker" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" class="datePicker" disabled="disabled" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>   
                             </script> 
</asp:Content>
```

and the js file where I keep my form object (with all the functions and the observables etc.) has this code:

```
....
....    
self.tasks = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.addTask = function () {
        self.tasks.push({'isSelected': '', 'CableCodeId': '' });
    };
....
....
```

But even though when i Load the page I get no js errors when I try to add a row to my table using the addTask function I get an **Error: Expected identifier, string or number.**

I have tried taking off the single quotes from isSelected and CableCodeId but still nothing.

I have also tried to get the second data-bind off (the one regarding the CableCode) so I can only check the first one (isSelected) but I still get the same error.

I am also using IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

why do you have a $ around your binding params?

```
checked: ${isSelected}
```

remove that and try again.

```
checked: isSelected
```

And see if that works.